# Help in new admin tab!

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-community

I followed this tutorial http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2012/02/08/magento-create-your-own-admin-controller-in-a-new-tab/. And my objective is the admin go to one of this pages and it asks some input. How can I do that ? Everytime I click on one of those pages 'Index Action' and 'List Action' I get page not found. Please need help doing this :/

CustomController.php

```
<?php

class Curiosidade_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml_CustomController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
            ->_title($this->__('Index Action'));

        // my stuff

        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function listAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout()
            ->_setActiveMenu('mycustomtab')
            ->_title($this->__('List Action'));

        // my stuff

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
?>
```

I need help where `// my stuff` is, because I don't know what to do next ?

Comment: I need more information. Please add your config.xml and adminhtml.xml as well; I need to see your routes and ACL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the following in your config.xml so that the route is defined.

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <curiosidade_createadmin before="Mage_Adminhtml">Curiosidade_CreateAdminController_Adminhtml</curiosidade_createadmin >
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```